# How to kill a PHP process?

Tags: php, kill-process

Is it possible to label a PHP process and kill it when necessary?

**Why?**
I have an jQuery application that when a user "Saves", a POST is sent to my PHP script. The PHP script is pretty intensive and can take awhile, but the processing is done on the server behind the scenes and is transparent to the user (When I say transparent, I mean the user can be doing stuff in jQuery on the front-end and not realize that the PHP script is still processing). As such, it's possible that the user saves again before the first PHP save operation finishes.

So my question is, how can I kill the last PHP save process (if it's not yet finished) and start the save process again?

Comment: it'd be trivial to stop the second save from happening, but the other way around seems tricky.

Comment: I think you can limit the execution time in php.ini

Comment: If I limit the execution time though, the save operation may not finish when I want it to

Comment: This is like something wrong. You should not allow such interruption because it may cause inconsistent state of your data. Insetead I'd recommend to suspend current saving process and place all such processes into one queue.

Comment: @Alma Do, I think you're probably right that I should queue the data to save.

Comment: It'd probably be simpler to have the AJAX call disable the save button, and re-enable it after the response comes back from the server.

Comment: Sure it would be helpful if you would disable the save button unless you received a response from server. However, this would not prevent somebody from calling the save url directly, multiple times. I'm with @AlmaDo, a stable solution would require the jobs to be queued and executed one after another, meaning both saves would happen. You might have a look at [RabittMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or even [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

Comment: I would suggest 2 ways for that. 1. Disable your button when user clicked. 2. you may also add some random id that let PHP application know that it is come from single form and process only one time. There are nothing to do with php process except you want to ensure that all query will insert to database, you may use ignore_user_abort() function.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding help to this particular question, I will say that the first approach is wrong. Your data or transaction will become inconsistent. So the solution should be first in php use PDO object to complete the transaction. Benefit would be that if the process fails in between the transaction can be reverted back.

Second in jquery use the $.ajaxComplete() method to for see any future event . let a handler to see that the task is completed and inform the user about its status.

I can give examples if you required

Comment: What does PDO has to do with transactions? (I'm even don't mentioning that saving process may involve lots of transactions) Also, OP even didn't mentioned that he's speaking about DBMS. The entire point of this question is in different thing.

Comment: Consider posting a code sample as well to show/describe exactly what you meant.